# Mutual Information of Correlated Bivariate Uniform Distribution

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy

We have correlated bivariate uniform distribution, where X and Y have a correlation coefficient $\rho$  and they uniformly distributed in the following rectangle. What is the mutual information of $X$ and $Y$?

[image]

Note that this shape is obtained by transforming the bivariate uniform distribution which $X_1$, $Y_1$ are uniformly distributed in the $[0,1]^2$. 
The transformation is as follows:

$ U=[X_1,Y_1] = uniform-rand(2,n)$

$\begin{gathered}
  C = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1&\rho  \\ 
  \rho &1 
\end{array}} \right] 
\\
  V = eigenVector[C] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&1 \\ 
  1&1 
\end{array}} \right] 
\\
  E = eigenValue[C] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {1 - \rho }&0 \\ 
  0&{1 + \rho } 
\end{array}} \right]
 \\ 
\end{gathered} $

$W = V*Sqrt(E)  $

$[X,Y] = (W*U)' $

Comment: What is stopping you in the computation of $I(X,Y)=\mathbb E(\log(f(X,Y)/(f_X(X)f_Y(Y))))$?

Comment: @did: I tried to compute it, but I could not find a correct solution. I found MI=0. However it is wrong.